# Adding Logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Studying for my midterm.

Solve the following algebraically:

$$\log_2x+\log_2(x+4)=5$$

So I know that $\log_b(mn)=\log_b(n)+\log_b(m)$ therefore:

$$5=\log_2(x(x+4))$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$5=\log_2(x^2+4x)$$
$$5=2^{x^2+4x}$$

Now I don't know how to solve for x at this point. I'm stuck. Please let me know if I've done anything wrong in my calculations. The answer key says that $x=4$.

Thanks.

Comment: if $a=\log_b(c)\implies c=b^a$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rewrote the expression incorrectly. It should be $x^2 + 4x = 2^5$.

Answer (score 2):

You just used the rules of logarithms incorrectly at your last step.

It should be $x^2 + 4x = 2^5$ - remember that $a = \log_b c$ means $b^a = c$.